# Extract part of a string as a Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in my source table called `Name`
But that field has the full name of a person including the first, last and middle name. In my resulting table I want to split them into 3 different columns. Note : Not all names have middle names in them.

```
Example :

In the source table

Name : Kennedy, John F
Name : Paul, Sean

In the destination field I want

LastName :  Kennedy
FirstName : John
MiddleName : F 

LastName : Paul
FirstName : Sean
MiddleName : Null
```

I managed to write the SQL Query to get the LastName but couldn't figure out about the first and Middle names.

```
Code for LastName :

 CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX(',', (RTRIM([NAME]))) > 0 
                THEN    LEFT((RTRIM([NAME])),CHARINDEX(',',(RTRIM([NAME])))-1)
                ELSE    RTRIM([NAME])
 END as LastName
```

I am using SQL Server as RDBMS

Comment: it'd be the same type of logic you're already using. find first comma, find first space AFTER the comma - everything in between is the "last name", everything AFTER that space is the "middle name".

Comment: are you using sql server 2016?

Comment: yes I am using 2016

Comment: Did you try `String_split` function in 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try ParseName()

```
Declare @String varchar(100)='Kennedy, John F'

Select LastName=ParseName(Replace(@String,' ','.'),3)
      ,FirstName=ParseName(Replace(@String,' ','.'),2)
      ,MiddleName=ParseName(Replace(@String,' ','.'),1)
```

Returns

```
LastName    FirstName   MiddleName
Kennedy,    John        F
```

Comment: when I ran n the table by replacing @string with source column name t resulted in a new table with Nulls

Comment: @HadoopAddict All NULL or just some nulls?

Comment: Most of the rows , except for 5-6 in a total result set of million records

Comment: By the way not all names have the middle name in them. Only few of them  . Sorry did not add this in question

Comment: @HadoopAddict added another answer to trap nulls

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,FullName varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Kennedy,  John F'),
(2,'Smith, Jame')

;with cteBase as (
    Select ID
          ,NewString = Replace(Replace(Replace(LTrim(RTrim(FullName)),' ','.'),',',''),'..','.')
          ,Pos=IIF(ParseName(Replace(Replace(RTrim(LTrim(FullName)),'  ',' '),' ','.'),3) is null,2,3)
     From @YourTable
)
Select ID
      ,LastName   = IsNull(ParseName(NewString,Pos-0),'')
      ,FirstName  = IsNull(ParseName(NewString,Pos-1),'')
      ,MiddleName = IsNull(ParseName(NewString,Pos-2),'')
 From cteBase
```

Returns

```
LastName    FirstName   MiddleName
Kennedy,    John        F
Smith,      Jame
```

Comment: Thanks for another answer , any idea how to get rid of the comma ','  in the LastName ?

Comment: @HadoopAddict LastName=Replace(ParseName(Replace(FullName,' ','.'),Pos),',','')

Comment: It is also failing if the Person has no Middle name 

Eg : Smith, Jame results in FirstName as : Smith but it should be last name..

Comment: @HadoopAddict Not in the example listed above,  Last name is smith and first name is Jame.   Data issue?   i.e. double spaces?  Leading spaces?

Comment: I have trailing spaces after the first name ..even if I remove all the trailing spaces your code is giving me lastname as Empty ..MiddleName as Jame FirstName as Smith

Comment: @HadoopAddict I modified my answer to trap leading/trailing and DOUBLE Spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
  --1.Create a Function
    Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetName]
    (
        @Descripcion nvarchar(max),
        @Tipo nvarchar(50)
    )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(MAX)

        declare @Nombre nvarchar(max) = @Descripcion
        declare @Letra nvarchar(1)= ''
        Declare @PrimerBlanco int  = 0
        Declare @Conjunto nvarchar(50)=''
        Declare @Entrada int = 1
        Declare @FueLetra int = 0

        Declare @LastName nvarchar(500)
        Declare @FirstName nvarchar(500)
        Declare @MiddleName nvarchar(500)
        Declare @Resultado nvarchar(500)

        while 1 = 1
        begin 

            set @Letra = LEFT(@Nombre,1)
            set @Conjunto = @Conjunto +''+@Letra

            if @Letra = ' '  and @FueLetra = 1 
            begin 
                set @PrimerBlanco = @PrimerBlanco + 1

                if @PrimerBlanco = 1
                begin 

                    if @Entrada = 1
                    begin 
                        set @Entrada = @Entrada + 1
                        set @LastName = ltrim(rtrim(@Conjunto))
                        GOTO Fin
                    end 

                    if @Entrada = 2
                    begin 
                        set @Entrada = @Entrada + 1
                        set @FirstName = ltrim(rtrim(@Conjunto))
                        GOTO Fin
                    end 

                    if @Entrada = 3
                    begin 
                        set @Entrada = @Entrada + 1
                        set @MiddleName = ltrim(rtrim(@Conjunto))
                        GOTO Fin
                    end 

                    Fin:  
                    set @Conjunto = ''
                    set @FueLetra = 0
                end 

            end 
            else 
            begin 
                set @PrimerBlanco = 0
                if @Letra  = ' '
                begin 
                    set @FueLetra = 0
                end 
                else 
                begin   
                    set @FueLetra = 1
                end 
            end 

            if @Nombre = ''
            begin 
                break
            end 

            Set @Nombre = substring(@Nombre ,2,len(@Nombre))
        end 

        if @tipo = 'LN'
        begin 
            set @Resultado = @LastName
        end 

        if @tipo = 'FN'
        begin 
            set @Resultado = @FirstName
        end 

        if @tipo = 'MN'
        begin 
            set @Resultado = @MiddleName
        end 

        RETURN @Resultado ;
    END    

    --2. Get the value(No matter white space)
Declare @Table as table 
(
    Name nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @Table values ( '              Kennedy,               John                 F')
insert into @Table values ('           Paul,            Sean')

select 
[dbo].[fn_GetName](name,'LN') as LastName,
[dbo].[fn_GetName](name,'FN') as FirstName,
[dbo].[fn_GetName](name,'MN') as MiddleName
from @Table
```

Comment: It might be helpful for this answer to provide a little background and context, since the code is quite lengthy.